# VBA: Simple Date Macro that does not work

Tags: vba, excel

I have two text boxes with for two dates to be typed in both boxes respectively. I want the macro to go through a column of dates and hide all dates that are **not** in between the two dates typed in the text boxes. The first text box date should be further in the past then the second text box date.

I have the following code:

```
Set ws2 = Sheets("Test")

Dim StartDate As String
Dim EndDate As String

ws2.Range("G2").Value = TXTDate1.Text
ws2.Range("G3").Value = TXTDate2.Text

StartDate = ws2.Range("G2").Value ' Start Date in  test tab
EndDate = ws2.Range("G3").Value

StartDate = Trim(ws2.Range("G2").Value)
EndDate = Trim(ws2.Range("G3").Value) **'Reverses the format from American date format to English date format**

Set temprange = ActiveSheet.Range("D5").End(xlDown)
Set temprange = Range(Range("D6"), temprange)


For Each z In temprange

z.EntireRow.Hidden = True

If TXTDate1.Value <> "" Then

If z.Offset(0, 5).Value > StartDate Then

If  z.Offset(0, 5).Value < EndDate Then **'PART THAT IS NOT WORKING**

z.EntireRow.Hidden = False

End If

End If

End If

Next z
```

The problem is the second condition is not working. The macro is not recognising dates that are before the End date. How do I enable the macro to recognise the 2nd Condition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used the [AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221844%28v=office.11%29.aspx) to show/hide the dates based upon your *startdate* and *enddate* vars.

```
Sub hide_dates()
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet, tempRange As Range
    Dim StartDate As String
    Dim EndDate As String

    Set ws2 = Sheets("Test")
    ws2.Range("G2").Value = TXTDate1.Text
    ws2.Range("G3").Value = TXTDate2.Text

    StartDate = Format(DateValue(ws2.Range("G2").Value), "mm/dd/yyyy")
    EndDate = Format(DateValue(ws2.Range("G3").Value), "mm/dd/yyyy")

    With ActiveSheet
        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
        Set tempRange = .Range(.Range("D5"), .Range("D5").End(xlDown))
        With tempRange
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=">=" & StartDate, _
                 Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & EndDate, _
                 VisibleDropDown:=False
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

I've hidden the small drop-down arrow normally associated with an .AutoFilter. You will have to change the format masks to a EN-UK format to match your data (d/m/yy...?).

The rows can be 'unhidden' through conventional means or by using the Clear command on Data ► Sort & Filter or simply turning the .AutoFilter off.